# Is there an alternative wrap for spring rolls other than rice paper?

Tags: asian-cuisine

I've been making spring rolls (the deep-fried variety) for some time now, and they are really good, but I've noticed some Asian restaurants use something else for wrapping them than the generic, translucent 'rice paper' I get at the store. Theirs are often smoother, yellowish and opaque, like in [this photo from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spring_rolls_on_sale.jpg). A new book on Thai cuisine I got just recently also has them looking like that in the pohotos and it mentions some mysterious "spring roll wads" which I've yet to come across in any store in my country. Anyways, what is it exactly, can I make some of my own and if so, how?

**EDIT:** Also, does the preparation of the rolls differ any when using an alternative wrapper, or can I just deep-fry them just the same?

Comment: I didn't know rice paper rolls *could* be deep fried. I've always used them for "fresh rolls", like this: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42177/can-lettuce-wraps-be-less-messy/42245#42245 Now I am going to have to try frying them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-rice paper rolls are probably made with wheat flour instead of rice flour, so they should be just as sturdy and stand up to deep frying as well or better than rice paper, which has always been fairly delicate and hard to work with in my limited experience.

Here is an image of flour egg roll wrappers in their uncooked state:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know how to make these?

Comment: Here is a recipe I found that seems very similar to the recipe I remember watching my uncle make: http://chinesefood.about.com/od/dimsumeggrolls/r/eggrollwraps.htm

Comment: Makes me wish I had me an uncle who made spring rolls. :) Although I have to admit mine managed to stun me with his way of making "potato pancakes" by cutting potatoes into thin slices which he then put on the hot iron top of an old coal stove. Tasted surprisingly well too! :D

Comment: Basically, they're pasta. If you have a pasta roller, that works great for making egg-roll wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prepare my spring roll warps fresh.
Use
2 cups of multipurpose flour (maida)
a pinch of salt
one egg
some water

Mix the above ingredients well to make a soft dough.
Let the dough rest for about 30 mins.
Make small balls of the dough and then roll them out into thin wraps.
Roast these wraps on a hot pan till very slightly brown.
Now you can use these wraps for your spring rolls and deep fry them.
These wraps get really crispy on deep frying.
You can also store these wraps in the refrigerator freezer and whenever you wish to use them first roast them slightly and then use. They stay good in the freezer for 8-10 days.

Comment: The recipe sounds good, but for wrapping, well-developed gluten produces better results. I would recommend adding two kneading steps, one before and one after resting - this will probably improve the texture (unless you are opposed to some additional cheapness).